# Cholesterol: What is the upper limit for VLDL and how do you lower the levels?

Tags: nutrition, diet, cholesterol

Linked to [Cholesterol: How can you lower LDL and maintain OR raise HDL?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25100/7951)

> Everywhere I look online (e.g. [Cleveland Clinic](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/articles/11920-cholesterol-numbers-what-do-they-mean)), it says about keeping LDL (Low Density Lipoproteins) to less than 100 mg/dL and where possible raise HDL (High Density Lipoproteins) to 50mg/dL or higher and reaching this is considered to be good. HDL of 60 or more is considered to be optimum and a protection against heart disease.

I cannot find any figures for Very-low-density lipoproteins (VLDL) but the Cleveland Clinic gives a **Non-HDL** limit of

> Less than 130 mg/dL.

Does that mean that the VLDL level should be lower than 30mg/dL considering the 100mg/dL limt for LDL?

How do you lower the VLDL levels?